# python how to loop jira tickets and write into json format file

Tags: json, python-2.7, jira

Python 2.x
Hi, I want to loop thru jira tickets and write 2 values into json format file.

```
The output file should look like this:
[
{"id": "jira-1234", "summary": "ticket 1"},
{"id": "jira-1235", "summary": "ticket 2"}
]
```

Here is what my code looks like right now:

```
from credentials import username, password
from jira.client import JIRA

query = 'project = DEV AND fixVersion = \"Sprint 123\"'

options = {'server': 'https://myjiraserver.localdomain.com'}
jira = JIRA(options)
jira = JIRA(basic_auth=(username, password))
issues = jira.search_issues(query, maxResults = 500)

for value in issues:
    for version in value.fields.fixVersions:
        print value.key, value.fields.summary
```

---

```
Output:
jira-1234  ticket 1
jira-1235  ticket 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working a bit better now, but the code still not dumping to json correctly.

```
mydict = {}
for value in issues:
        mydict.update({'id' : value.key, 'summary' : value.fields.summary})
        with open('result-test.json', 'a') as f:
                json.dump(mydict, f)

The output is looking like this:
{"id": "jira-1234", "summary": "ticket 1"}
{"id": "jira-1235", "summary": "ticket 2"}

Not sure what I'm missing on the json.dump here. json validator says:
python -mjson.tool result-test.json
Extra data: line 1 column X - line 1 column X
```